# Dynamically assigning border radius to the li first-child in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, css

I am trying to create a navigation bar with rounded corners for the first and last children (using an unordered list). I want to use the onclick javascript function and dynamically assign rounded corners within javascript. Here is my code which I tried. Can anyone please point me to the reason and/or suggest a solution or resource? Thanks a lot in advance.

HTML:

```
                   <nav>
                        <ul id="navBar">
                            <li><a href="#" title="View"><div class="menu" onClick="select(this)">View</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Duplicate"><div class="menu" onClick="select(this)">Duplicate</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Edit"><div class="menu" onClick="select(this)">Edit</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Delete"><div class="menu" onClick="select(this)">Delete</div></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
```

Javascript:

```
  document.getElementById('ul#navBar li:first-child').style.MozBorderRadiusTopleft = '13px';
document.getElementById('ul#navBar li:first-child').style.MozBorderRadiusBottomleft = '13px';
document.getElementById('ul#navBar li:last-child').style.MozBorderRadiusTopRight = '13px';
document.getElementById('ul#navBar li:last-child').style.MozBorderRadiusBottomRight = '13px';
```

Comment: `.getElementById('ul#navBar li:first-child')` is not valid... You can use `.querySelector` to do this. But, instead of applying the style with javascript, I'd recommend adding a class to the first element and styling with CSS.

Comment: Is there a reason not to put it in the CSS statically?

Comment: Where would the click that triggers this be? In which element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS for your stylesheet:

```
.is-rounded li:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 13px 0 0 13px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px 0 0 13px;
    border-radius: 13px 0 0 13px;
}

.is-rounded li:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 13px 13px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 13px 13px 0;
    border-radius: 0 13px 13px 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function makeRounded(e) {
   document.querySelector('#navBar').className += 'is-rounded';
}

document.querySelector('#el').addEventListener('click', makeRounded, false);
```

This assumes than an element with the id of "el" is the element that, when clicked, triggers the whole thing.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/cgrFe/3/

You seem to know very little about this. A few books to get you started: http://domscripting.com/book/ and http://domenlightenment.com/ . The last of the two is fairly new, but must be good.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am trying to do this without using JQuery-- just pure css and Javascript. I just want that on click, the first and last menu items should retain it's rounded corners!

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` does not take a selector as its argument. Only a valid id of the element is required for its usage. You're probably thinking about [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$('ul#navBar li:first-child').css({
    MozBorderRadiusTopleft: '13px'
});

$('navBar li:first-child').css({
    MozBorderRadiusBottomleft: '13px'
});

$('ul#navBar li:last-child').css({
    MozBorderRadiusTopRight: '13px'
});

$('navBar li:last-child').css({
    MozBorderRadiusBottomRight: '13px'
});
```

Comment: True but there is much more to say about the very idea of styling the via javascript only...

Answer (score 0):

I would make things really simple. Start by defining two css classes for rounded corners:

```
 .round-top {
      MozBorderRadiusTopleft:13px;
      MozBorderRadiusTopRight:13px;

  }

  .round-bottom {
      MozBorderRadiusBottomleft:13px;
      MozBorderRadiusBottomRight:13px;
   }
```

Then you can simply add/remove the class from the elements that you are interested in.
In javascript:

```
   var container = document.getElementById(navBar);
   container.firstChild.setAttribute("class", "round-top");
   container.lastChild.serAttribute("class", "round-bottom");
```

Jquery:

```
   $('#navBar li:first-child').addClass('round-top');
   $('#navBar li:last-child').addClass('round-bottom');
```

A full event listener would be something like:

```
 function addBorders(){
     var container = document.getElementById(navBar);
     container.firstChild.setAttribute("class", "round-top");
     container.lastChild.serAttribute("class", "round-bottom");
 }

 //target is the element you want to trigger the event
 target.addEventListener("click", addBorders, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery, you can do it in next way
intead "border", "3px double red" you should use your styles

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         var Menu = {
            rootEl: null,

            Init: function (idRootEl) {
                this.rootEl = $(idRootEl);
                this.initItems();
                this.setFirstElSeleceted();
            },
            setFirstElSeleceted: function () {
                $($(this.rootEl).find('li')[0]).css("border", "3px double red");
            },
            initItems: function () {
                var self = this;


                $(self.rootEl).find('li').each(function (indx) {
                    $(this).click(function () {
                        self.removeSelection();
                        self.setSelected(this);
                    });

                });
            },
            setSelected: function (el) {
                $(el).css("border", "3px double red");
            },
            removeSelection: function () {
                var self = this;
                $(self.rootEl).find('li').each(function (el) {
                    $(this).css("border", "");
                });
            }
        };




        $(function() {
            Menu.Init('ul#navBar');
         });
        </script>
```